# match a string at the beginning of the line in Python

Tags: python

I want to search for certain pattern at the beginning of every line inside a text file.

Here is the contents of text file:

```
module abc ( A, B, C, NSUP, PSUP, SEL );
input NSUP;
input PSUP;
input SEL;
inout A;
inout B;
output C;
//sample text input pins
//sample text output pins
```

I want output as

```
NSUP
PSUP
SEL
A
B
C
```

I tried below code but it prints an empty list as output:

```
fh=open("VamsModel","r")
contents=fh.read()
inoutPortList=re.compile(r'^(input|output|inout)\s+(\w+)')
matches = inoutPortList.finditer(contents)

for match in matches:
    print(match.group(2))
```

If I remove "^" from re.compile pattern then it works but then it wont look for patterns only at the begining.

```
inoutPortList=re.compile(r'(input|output|inout)\s+(\w+)')
```

above regex will also output last two lines(shown below) from my text file which I don't want:

```
//sample text input pins
//sample text output pins
```

Any ideas why my regex not working when I am using "^" ??

Comment: tried `re.compile(r'^(input|output|inout)\s+(\w+)',flags=re.M)` ?

Answer (score 6):

With `^` on a whole buffer, you're looking for your expression at the start of the buffer.

To look for the expression at the start of each line use multiline flag:

```
inoutPortList=re.compile(r'^(input|output|inout)\s+(\w+)',flags=re.M)
```

output:

```
NSUP
PSUP
SEL
A
B
C
```

Aside: with regex module, always pass the flags as keyword parameters: `flags=re.M` not just `re.M`. It works with `re.compile` but not with `re.sub` because "count" parameter comes first, which creates weird issues.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the re.MULTILINE (re.M shorthand) flag to indicate that ^ matches at start of line rather than string:

```
inoutPortList=re.compile(r'^(input|output|inout)\s+(\w+)', re.M)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what strings you're looking for you could use `startswith` in place of regular expressions

```
if line.startswith(("input", "output", "inout")):
    print(line.split(" ", 1)[1])
```